# Android ViewFlipper With Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, viewflipper

Is it possible to use ViewFlipper between two activities, and at the same send parameters between them?

Like, on the first view, two buttons are used, depending on what button, it should be switched over to the over view (using ViewFlipper) and using some different logic depending on the button pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create two classes and have them inflate the desired layout. In each class you could have the different logic. Your activity would then only hold the ViewFlipper and the logic for switching to next/previous.

```
public class ViewFlipperActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
      super( savedInstanceState );
      setContentView( R.layout.my_viewFlipper_lauout );

      flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.viewFlipper );

      FirstView first = new FirstView( this, flipper ); 
      flipper.addView( first );

      SecondView second = new SecondView( this, flipper );
      flipper.addView( second );

      first.setDataPasser( second );
      second.setDataPasser( first );
   }
}
```

**First View**

```
public class FirstView extends LinearLayout implements DataPasser {
   private ViewFlipper flipper;
   private DataPasser dataPasser;

   public FirstView( Context context, ViewFlipper flipper ) {
      super(context);
      inflate( ... );
      this.flipper = flipper;

      // Do other stuff.
   }

   protected void setDataPasser( DataPasser dataPasser ) {
     this.dataPasser = dataPasser;
   }

   //Implement the other methods required by your interface.
}
```

**Second View**

```
public class SecondView extends LinearLayout {
   private ViewFlipper flipper;
   private DataPasser dataPasser;

   public SecondView( Context context, ViewFlipper flipper ) {
      super(context);
      inflate( ... );
      this.flipper = flipper;

      // Do other stuff.
   }

   protected void setDataPasser( DataPasser dataPasser ) {
     this.dataPasser = dataPasser;
   }

   //Implement the other methods required by your interface.
}
```

Then when you need to change view when on either FirstView or SecondView, you call `flipper.showNext()` or `flipper.showPrevious()`

**EDIT**

To pass data between the two views, you can either implement some methods in the activity class for this purpose and then let the two views hold a reference to the activity. Another alternative is to create an interface that the two views must implement:

```
interface DataPasser {
  void setDataPasser( DataPasser dataPasser ); //To be able to add each view to the other.
  void passData( Data data ); //Or other methods needed to pass the data.
}
```

Comment: where can i pass parameter in this example?

Comment: I have edited the above answer to fit your needs more accurately.

Comment: So what would viewFlipper look like from R.id.viewFlipper?

Comment: @Igor G.: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Look at your code for ViewFlipperAtivity: you have R.id.viewFlipper.  That denotes an XML file.  Something akin to:
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:clickable="true">
 <include android:id="@+id/first_screen" layout="@layout/first_view" />
 <include android:id="@+id/second_screen" layout="@layout/second_view" />
</ViewFlipper>

Comment: Yes, there needs to be a `ViewFlipper` in the layout `my_viewFlipper_layout.xml`. It is however just empty because we add the children in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Name should tell you.You can flip between two views not between two intents.So better try to flip between two views rather than two activities.

Comment: then how can i pass parameter with view flipper.

Comment: In that case you can use yout own logic.No other choice i think.

Comment: any idea do you have for this issue?